# How to find diagonalizing matrix in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix

How can one find matrix $X$ such that $X^\dagger Y X = D$ is a diagonal matrix. In particular for Y defined as

`Y = ( { {a, b, 0, 0}, {a, b, 0, 0}, {0, 0, c, d}, {0, 0, a, d} } );`

Where $a,b,c,d$ are in general complex, and $X^\dagger = ConjugateTranspose[X]$.

Comment: Do you consider that X is unitary ? That is that ConjugateTranspose of X is equal to the inverse of X ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that matrix is unitarily diagonalizable without extra assumptions on the values that appear. Using `Inverse` instead of `ConjugateTranspose` we can do

```
Block[{Y = ({
            {a, b, 0, 0},
            {a, b, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, c, d},
            {0, 0, a, d}
            }),
    values, vectors, X
    },
    {values, vectors} = Eigensystem[Y];
    X = Transpose[vectors];
    Inverse[X] . Y . X // FullSimplify
 ]
```

Which provides the diagonal matrix $D$:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & a+b & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{4 a d+(c-d)^2}+c+d\right) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{4 a d+(c-d)^2}+c+d\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

with $X$ given by:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -\frac{b}{a} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -\frac{\sqrt{4 a d+(c-d)^2}-c+d}{2 a} & \frac{\sqrt{4 a d+(c-d)^2}+c-d}{2 a} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Edit: You can also use JordanDecomposition:

```
Block[
    {Y = {
            {a, b, 0, 0},
            {a, b, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, c, d},
            {0, 0, a, d}},
    X, D
    },
    {X, D} = JordanDecomposition[Y];
    MatrixForm /@ {X, D}
 ]
```

(Warning, don't actually call a symbol `D`.)

Comment: The matrix is diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis if and only if it is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) that is, if and only if it commutes with its conjugate transpose. That is the constraint for the inverse of X to be its ConjugateTranspose. If {a,b,c,d} are real the condition for the matrix Y to be normal can be found using `Reduce[matrix . Transpose[matrix] - Transpose[matrix] . matrix ==    0, {a, b, c, d}]`. That lead to `(b == a && d == a) || (b == a && c == -a && d == -a)`

Comment: However the user considers {a,b,c,d} are complex which leads to longer output from `Reduce`. That said the user did not specify whether the ConjugateTranspose should be its inverse. So the problem might be more general and maybe there is no constraint on Y